# Saving Data from Dropdown to Repository

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

So I have my Viewbag that pulls through a dropdown list in my create razor view which uses the follownig Code:

Controller

```
 ViewBag.ActionTypes = new SelectList(query.AsEnumerable(), "ActionTypeID", "ActionTypeTitle");
```

Then my Razor does this;

```
  @Html.DropDownList("ActionTypeID", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.ActionTypes)
```

I'm stuck on what to put in my Post Method and how to get the value from the dropdown list?

can anyone point me in the right direction

Comment: Classic ASP never supported C# or the MVC framework. Please be more careful with your tagging.

Comment: Sorry I put in ASP and it defaulted to classic

Comment: I believe you mean "defaulted". Defected means something else.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a model called ActionType:

```
public class ActionType
{
    public int ActionTypeID { get; set; }

    ...
}
```

Since your SelectList using this same property name, the ModelBinder will take care of setting the correct POSTed value:

```
new SelectList(query.AsEnumerable(), "ActionTypeID", "ActionTypeTitle");
--------------------------------------------^
```

Just remember to add a property with the same name to the Model class you're using in your Action:

```
-------------------------------v  Add the property to this class.
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(SomeModel model)
{
}
```

---

Here's an example. Imagine you have the following Entities already generated by Entity Framework:

```
Person       Country
-------      -------
PersonID     CountryID
FullName     Name
CountryID


[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(PersonModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        DbEntities db = new DbEntities();
        Person person = new Person();
        person.FullName = model.FullName;
        person.CountryID = model.CountryID; // This value is from the DropDownList.

        db.AddToPersons(person);
        db.SaveChanges();

        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");       
    }

    // Something went wrong. Redisplay form.
    return View(model);
}
```

It's just a matter of setting the POSTed ID value to the foreign key property of the entity object.

Comment: How to I save the returned value to My Dababase, please can you used an example

Comment: @StefanGowlar: That depends on what you're using for the backend and the architecture of your project. Are you using the repository pattern?

Comment: Yes I am, could you show me an example to put in the controller and I can change it?

Comment: In my Repository I have "void InsertActionType(ActionType ActionType);" Then in EFRepository I have "  public void InsertActionType(ActionType ActionType)
        {
            context.ActionTypes.Add(ActionType);
        }"

Comment: So I should be able to do this?    var viewbag = Action.ActionTypeID;
                ActionRepository.InsertActionType(viewbag);

Comment: @StefanGowlar: It depends on what InsertActionType() does and what type of parameter it receives.